# Function of random variable

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

If I have a random variable $X$ which has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, what is the approximate expression of $\log(X)$ and $\sqrt{X}$? Do I assume normal approximation or use Taylor expansion?

Comment: If this is for homework or self-study, you should add the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: We can't tell you what you're expected to assume, but my guess is that it's probably Taylor expansion that's is being looked for.

Comment: Be careful: $\log(X)$ and $\sqrt{X}$ are not even properly defined if $\Pr(X<0)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

without knowing the distribution of $X$ you can't find the mean and variance of $f(X)$ in your cases. Taylor expansion will not help because you only know first two moments, which at best would help you evaluate a couple of terms in the Taylor series.

Normal assumption can't be made arbitrarily. If you think your X is from normal distribution, then you basically defined it by first two moments, i.e. you know the distribution. Computing moments of a transformed variable would have been trivial in this case for some functions.

For $\log(X)$ and $\sqrt{X}$ you have an issue: what are you going to do with negative X? Are you willing to go into complex numbers domain?

Comment: In place of "$\log(X)$" you must mean $\exp(X)$, because the logarithm has similar problems with negative arguments as the square root.

Comment: @whuber, my bad, corrected

Answer (score 0):

You mean the mean of $\log(x)$ and $\sqrt{x}$? Yes, it depends on the distribution. Using a normal distribution or log-normal or gamma will give you different values.

Comment: Could you please amplify this answer and provide enough detail to be useful to the O.P.?

Comment: I don't have the distribution for X at hand. I was only given that it has mean mu and variance sigma^2.

Comment: User2350622, please edit your question to reflect that crucial information. Before you do so, though, search our site for [delta method](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+method) because what you find will likely answer your question.

Comment: What would be the distribution of $\log(X)$ and/or $\sqrt{X}$ when $X$is a normal random variable? Especially when the normal random variable has significant probability of taking on negative values?

Comment: Well first of all you can't take the log() or sqrt() of a negative number so a normal distribution is technically not going to work. If all you know is the mean and sigma then you simply don't have enough information to answer the question. To answer this, you are going to have to make additional assumptions. I'd suggest using the the gamma distribution because you can easily calculate the expectation value of sqrt(x). Note that the expectation value of log(x) is the entropy which is given here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: The beta distribution is even better because when you add a scale length, you have three free parameters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution That allows you to see that the expectation values of \sqrt(x) and \log(x) will vary based on the this third degree of freedom. You could vary those parameters within a reasonable range and see how much they vary.